# Fit an image in a paragraph to width of grandparent div

Tags: html, css

I feel like this should be really easy, but I've been playing with it for ages and haven't gotten anywhere.

I have a div, and my images inside it are set to width:100%. This works as you'd expect, with the images appearing edge to edge inside the div.

For paragraphs inside this div, I have padding.

What I'd like, is for images inside those paragraphs to also appear at the full width of the div (not the paragraph, which is narrower, due to the padding). However I do need to keep the padding, as I need it or the text.

**HTML** *(Which can't be changed)*:

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <img src="whatever" />
    <!-- this next image should be exactly the same width as the first one -->
    <p><img src ="whatever" /> This text still needs to be padded though.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    padding:15px;
}
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

I have tried adding a negative margin to the image (using the CSS below), which gets it over to the edge, but I can't accurately make it the same width as the div.

**CSS:**

```
p img {
    /*starts the img in the right place, but doesn't fix the width */
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right:-15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the css `calc` property. Try the code below. Keep in mind that `calc` does not work in some older browsers.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8Lb7t3t/6/

html

```
<div class='gp'>
    <img src='http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png'/>
    <p>
        <img class='img-pad' src='http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png'/>
        text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text textext text text text text text text
    </p>
</div>
```

css

```
.gp {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.img-pad {
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
p {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't do what I want. I probably should have been more clear, but I can't change the HTML - If I could do that, I'd just put the img outside the p tags. The situation is that this is for a Joomla template, and I need writers to be able to add their own images easily.

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/q8Lb7t3t/6/ if that works for you then I'll update my answer. But i'd recommend finding a way to change the html. That markup will be hard to maintain

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks Abdul! If you add this to your answer, I'll give it a tick :)